# Devise a program that counts the number of characters in its input up to the end of file

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()

{
    int ch;
    int numberOfCharacters = 0;
    printf("please enter a word, and ctrl + d to see the resault\n");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && isprint(ch))

    {
        numberOfCharacters++;
    }

    printf("The number of characters is %d", numberOfCharacters);

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a good code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't do much. But it is not bad. A few issues:

- main() should have parameters
- excess blank lines (lines 5, 12, 16, 18) spoil the appearance
- no \n on the last printf
- the spec doesn't say 'printable' characters, just characters.
- "please" needs a capital p and "resault" should be "result"

Comment: thank you! i know it dosent do much, but since im a newbie i would love to get feedback like you just wrote so i will know for next time or when i have bigger programs @WilliamMorris